# Visualisation of a boardgame

Tags: android, scaling

I'm new to android studio and I'm learning a lot right now. But I'm stuck now, I want to create something like a container for a 16x7 boardgame with individual fields. I think theres better ways to do this and I'm trying around since 2 hours, with no success. Right now I'm using a Grid View to display my String[] with an array adapter to a simple selectable list item, but it doesn't scale right and I need to scroll down to see all of the fields, which is bad for a videogame.

Tl,dr: I'd like to display an array of 112 elements like a boardgame, what container can I use to create those individual fields, maybe even set the amounts of rows(7) and columns(16), and display it simple like an actual boardgame?

Answer (score 0):

I would render bitmap tiles to the Canvas. Below code is just an outline:

```
// You will set this frameBuffer to an ImageView in the app's main screen.
// You should set the ImageView's ScaleType properly.
Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    TILE_SIZE * 16, TILE_SIZE * 7, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(frameBuffer);
Paint paint = new Paint();

for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        // You are supposed to define bitmapTiles.get() method elsewhere.
        canvas.drawBitmap(
            bitmapTiles.get(x, y), TILE_SIZE * x, TILE_SIZE * y, paint
        );
    }
}
```